# Why doesn't $(c-1)c^0+(c-1)c^1+...+(c-1)c^{z-2} \ge c^z$ hold?

Tags: inequality

I reached a point in my proof where i need to disprove the following:

> $$(c-1)c^0+(c-1)c^1+...+(c-1)c^{z-2} \ge c^z,$$ for integers $c>1, z>0$

I can manipulate it:
$$(c-1)(c^0+c^1+...+c^{z-2}) \ge (c)(c^{z-1}),$$ but then what?

How can i show that this is incorrect without using any example values for $c$ and $z$?

I need to show that this is incorrect for all $c$ and $z$, not just one example.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: sum the left hand side as a geometric series

Comment: Thanks @fGDu94 i just realized it!!